# Knockout binding with a customization in for each

Tags: jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I have a situation here for the knockout with for each binding with customization

Here is my code:

```
<div id="content-wrapper">

    <div id="akjsdbgb">
        <table>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: resultData">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: fieldName"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: fieldValue"></td>
                </tr>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

### Model:

```
    self.resultData = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.getResultData = function () {
        var data = Cobalt.Data.getResultData();
        self.resultData(data.searchDataList);
    };
};

Models.Field = function(data) {

    var self = this;
    self.fieldName = data.fieldName;
    self.fieldValue = data.fieldValue;

};
```

The problem is i need to create a tabular data from the resultData which is in fieldName and fieldValue formats and the table should be having two sets of data in a single tr means

4 's in a tr but the data array contains single fieldName and fieldValue; so we need to loop in a tr for two times of data and then increment it.

OUTPUT AS EXPECTED:

---

### | FieldName1 |FieldValue2  || FieldName3 |FieldValue4  |

### | FieldName5 | FieldValue6 || FieldName7 |FieldValue8  |

Comment: From your description I thought your output should be more like this:

| FieldName1 |FieldValue1 || FieldName2 |FieldValue2 |

| FieldName3 | FieldValue3 || FieldName4 |FieldValue4 |

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a computed which would pair items, something like the following:

```
self.rows = ko.computed(function(){
    var allItems = self.resultData();
    var rows = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = allItems.length; i < len; i = i+2){
        rows.push({
            leftItem: allItems[i],
            rightItem: i + 1 < len ? allItems[i + 1] : null
        });
    }
    return rows;
});
```

You would then bind to the `rows` property instead of binding directly to the `resultData` property.

EDIT: @GOK asked, in a comment, for a version which would allow customizable number of items in a single row.

You could achieve this easily by doing something like the following:

```
self.itemsOnEachRow = ko.observable(2);
self.rows = ko.computed(function(){
    var allItems = self.resultData();
    var itemsPerRow = self.itemsOnEachRow();
    var rows = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = allItems.length; i < len; i = i + itemsPerRow){
        var row = {};
        for(var itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < itemsPerRow; itemIndex++){
            var item = null;
            if (i + itemIndex < len){
                item = allItems[i + itemIndex];
            }
            row['item' + itemIndex] = item;
        }
        rows.push(row);
    }
    return rows;
});
```

Each row would then have properties named `item1`, `item2`, etc, to the number of items set by the `itemsOnEachRow` observable (some of these properties might hold a null reference, if the total item count isn't evenly divisible by the items per row count).

I have written a sample on this, which you can find on http://jsfiddle.net/af7P2/, but I do not suggest binding the table in the way it is done in that sample. I'm not sure how it would set up subscriptions, but it might subscribe a multitude of times to the `columns` computed, one time for each row. It's just there to show a sample of the `rows` computed, not for anything else.

If you want each row to be an array in itself, you could do it with the following code:

```
self.itemsOnEachRow = ko.observable(2);
self.rows = ko.computed(function(){
    var allItems = self.resultData();
    var itemsPerRow = self.itemsOnEachRow();
    var rows = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = allItems.length; i < len; i = i + itemsPerRow){
        var row = [];
        for(var itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < itemsPerRow; itemIndex++){
            var item = null;
            if (i + itemIndex < len){
                item = allItems[i + itemIndex];
            }
            row.push(item);
        }
        rows.push(row);
    }
    return rows;
});
```

The bindings for this version (which you can find at http://jsfiddle.net/af7P2/1/) is a bit better, since it doesn't use the `columns` computed one time for each row.

In general, this solution might not perform very well, depending on your situation. Any addition/removal of items to the `resultData` array, or a change to the `itemsOnEachRow` value, would rebind the whole table. Might not be a problem for you, just something to be aware of.

Comment: Can we customize the leftItem, rightItem to any number of times we need like item[i] or something which can be as item1, item2, item3...

Comment: @GOK I have updated the answer with samples for binding to a custom number of items on each row.