# Knockout Table View of Array list without Names

Tags: sql, arrays, knockout.js

I'm new to knockout and JS programming.  I have a JSON result set returned, that would be two nested arrays, like this wherein each array could be variable in size:

listToReturn

[0] Count:4 -------> [0] "CHANNEL", [1] "HOUR", [2] "DATE", [3] "TRANSACTION_CNT"

[1] Count:122 ----->

[0] 101, [1] 11, [2] 03/01/2014, [3] 400,

[4] 101, [5] 6, [7] 03/12/2014, [8] 232

(these are the individual values for the rows above that repeat)

I want to build table that displays these nicely.  Essentially, that will handle any result set that comes back with variable number of columns and data that will be populated in the table, like this:

CHANNEL     HOUR     DATE     TRANSACTION_CNT

101         12       03/01/2014   400

101         6        03/12/2014   232

I have the first part working for the column headers:

Within ViewModel:

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: 'Reports/GetReportData',
                    data: { requestObj: req },
                    contenttype: 'application/json',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    success: function(result) {
                        if (result) {


                            document.getElementById("reportOutputfieldSet").style.display = "block";

                            ko.utils.arrayForEach(result[0], function (data) {
                                self.cnames.push(data.replace(",", " "));
                            });
                            ko.utils.arrayForEach(result[1], function (data) {
                                self.cdata.push(data.replace(",", " "));
                    });
```

In the View:

```
                <tr data-bind="foreach: cnames" style="color: white; background-color: #003399; font-weight: bold; width: 600px">
                    <td data-bind="text: $data" style="width: 25%"></td>
                </tr>
```

After several different attempts to properly construct a display for the data, I'm coming up empty handed.  I first tried going through and getting the unique values for each one and displaying them in the UI, but that didn't work.  :(

```
                    var noColumns = result[0].length;

                    var thisArray = function () {
                        if (result[1].length === 0)
                            return [];
                        for (var column = 0; column < result[0].length - 1; column++) {

                            for (var row = column; row < result[1].length - 1; row++) {
                                if (row % noColumns == 0) {
                                    switch (column) {
                                        case 0:
                                            self.columnOne.push(result[1][row]);
                                            break;
                                        case 1:
                                            self.columnTwo.push(result[1][row]);
                                            break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return self.columnOne();
                    };
```

In the View:

```
            <tbody>
                <!-- ko foreach: columnOne -->
                <tr style="border-bottom: solid 1px #003399;">
                    <td data-bind="text: $data" style="width: 25%"></td>   
                     <!-- ko foreach: columnTwo -->
                    <td data-bind="text: $data" style="width: 25%"></td>   
                     <!-- /ko -->
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </tbody>
```

I have a feeling I need a custom ko.binding, but really at a loss as to how to get started with it.  Anyone's help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can u post the code using [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net). It will be easy to debug online

Comment: Just group the data into rows with `noColumns` values in each row. You can look at a sample at http://jsfiddle.net/fbq3h/ or look at the last solution in the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677432/knockout-binding-with-a-customization-in-for-each/21677728#21677728.

Comment: Thanks so much, Krishna and Robert.  Looking into it, will see if I can get it to work.  if not, I'll post on jfiddle.

Comment: This worked, Robert.  Thank you VERY much!  Had to modify it a bit for 'fit for purpose', but it broke the circular thinking cycle that I was trapped in.  Much appreciated.