# Knockout JS <table> output based on chosen <select> option

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Is it possible to bind columns of a table to the selected option inside a `<select>` element? My app currently works like this:

The selected option of `<select>`#1 defines what options should be displayed in `<select>`#2. This part of the app is completely dynamic and is working as it should.

What I now want to do is bind the columns inside of a table to the option that's selected in `<select>`#2.

By default there's 5 columns in the table: 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018 and I need these columns to bind to `<select>`#2. If 2016 is selected, then only 2016, 2017, 2018 should be shown in the table. If 2018 is selected, then only 2018 should be shown in the table, etc.

I'm guessing this will be possible using knockout but I'm not quite sure how to approach this.

Note: This is purely about showing/hiding table columns. Inside the cells of the table columns are binded numerical values which will multiply by each other in real-time when a value inside one of the cells is changed.

Comment: Please give more details. Is the data for table populated using knockout or is it static?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677432/knockout-binding-with-a-customization-in-for-each/21677728#21677728 which provides an answer for you.

Comment: The data that's populated is pulled from an array using knockout, but there's a % cell in each column which computes and updates the fetched values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
<select data-bind='options: availableYears, value: selectedYear'></select>
...
<td data-bind="visible: isYearAfter(2014, selectedYear)">2014</td>
<td data-bind="visible: isYearAfter(2015, selectedYear)">2015</td>
...

var viewmodel = {
    selectedYear: ko.observable(2014),
    availableYears: ko.observableArray([2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]),
    isYearAfter: function (year, referenceYear) {
        return referenceYear() < year;
    }
};
```

Example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/dP9Uu/1/

Comment: This looks to be what I need but now this is where things will get a little complicated... The year select and population popup are in two separate viewmodels which are bound at the end of their relative function.

Comment: Well that's another story!

Comment: Is it one you could possibly elaborate on?